# Maintain gradient size when element is resized

Tags: css, linear-gradients

How do I create a gradient that maintains its current size when the element or the container of the element is resized?

Box in 100% width:
[image: 100% bar]
Wanted result when width is reduced to 60% (notice the division on the colors should align with the original 100%):
[image: 60% bar current]
Current result when width is reduced to 60%:
[image: 60% bar expected]

I also need the `linear-gradient` to not have an absolute value ([such as the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38900237/fixed-background-gradient-with-dynamic-width)) as I will use it inside a dynamic width element.

```css
@keyframes resize {
  50% {
    width: 50%
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%
  }
}

.box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient( 90deg, red 50%, blue 50%);
  animation: resize linear 2s infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

define a fixed size for the gradient:

```css
@keyframes resize {
  50% {
    width: 50%
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%
  }
}

.box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient( 90deg, red 50%, blue 50%);
  background-size:100vw 100%; /* added */
  animation: resize linear 2s infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Or make it fixed:

```css
@keyframes resize {
  50% {
    width: 50%
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%
  }
}

.box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient( 90deg, red 50%, blue 50%) fixed;
  animation: resize linear 2s infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Or instead of animating the width, you can do a different animation that will produce the same visual using clip-path:

```css
@keyframes resize {
  0% {
    clip-path:inset(0 0% 0 0); /* width= 100% */
  }
  100% {
    clip-path:inset(0 50% 0 0); /* width= 50% */
  }
}

.box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient( 90deg, red 50%, blue 50%);
  animation: resize linear 1s infinite alternate;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```